# How to convert HashMap of Object and String[] to json

Tags: java, json, object, hashmap

Below is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<HierarchyFilter, String[]> filters = new HashMap();
    HierarchyFilter obj = new HierarchyFilter("name1", "type1", "value1");
    String[] a = new String[6];
    a[0]="String1";
    a[1]="String2";
    a[2]="String3";
    a[3]="String4";
    a[4]="String5";
    a[5]="String6";
    filters.put(obj, a);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(filters);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
  }
```

I am using jackson mapper. But my object is not getting converted properly.
Below is the out put what i receive:

```
{
  "com.remote.HierarchyFilter@63bd725" : [ "String1", "String2", "String3", "String4", "String5", "String6" ]
}
```

I receive the default toString of the Object.
please help

Comment: What output do you expect and why?

Comment: Actually I have a class with Has this HashMAp.
In UI i need to get the information of time of object String[] is mapped . So I am sending information as json to front end.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. Please edit your question to reflect the JSON you want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting Jackson to map the `"com.remote.HierarchyFilter@63bd725"` to JSON with the values `"name1", "type1", "value1"`, then you are expecting an **INVALID** json, which Jackson mapper wouldn't do.

The JSON map data structure is a JSON object data structure, which is a collection of name/value pairs, where the element names must be strings. The JSON map keys must also be strings because JSON map is a JSON object. So, when you try use `HierarchyFilter` key, it uses the `toString` method (a string value) of the object to use it as Key.

TO achieve what you need to send to UI, decide on a proper JSON structure contract and then design your Object classes/response objects accordingly.

Comment: thank you. I restructured my variable to Map<String, Map<String, Object>> filters and its working as expected